# Error con fechas a futuro con funcion time ago

Tags: php

Tengo esta funcion:

```
function nicetime($date){
if(empty($date)){
    return "No date provided";
}

$periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
$lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

$now = time();
$unix_date = strtotime($date);

   // check validity of date
if(empty($unix_date)){   
    return "Bad date";
}

// is it future date or past date
if($now > $unix_date){   
    $difference     = $now - $unix_date;
    $tense         = "ago";

} else {
    $difference     = $unix_date - $now;
    $tense         = "from now";
}

for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
    $difference /= $lengths[$j];
}

$difference = round($difference);

if($difference != 1) {
    $periods[$j].= "s";
}

return "$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";
}

<?=nicetime($row['fti']);?> <!-- $row viene de la base de datos con la fecha en formato 2019-03-10 -->
```

En la base de datos las fechas se guardan en este formato: `Y-m-d` - `2019-03-10`, pero tambien se guardan fechas de pedidos a futuro y ahi es donde empieza el problema, si la fecha del pedido es hoy me da como resultado `22 hours ago` y si la fecha del pedido es para el dia 20 de marzo el resultado es `less than 1 second ago` y tendria que decir `next day` o `next day` o `next month`. No se como arreglar esto teniendo en cuenta que el formato de fecha debe respetarse.

Comment: Y si mostras que tiene cada variable para saber que calculo se esta haciendo mal?

Comment: Listo, ya lo agregue

Comment: Solo agregaste la llamada. que tiene cada variable de las que estas calculando?

Comment: no te entiendo... disculpa

Comment: Loguea de alguna forma el valor que va tomando cada variable, asi podemos ver que datos estas llevando de cada lado

Comment: Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar funciones, si hago esto: `var_dump(get_time_ago($row['fti']));` el resultado es este: `24 hours ago string(12) "50 years ago" `

Comment: Cambien la funcion y trate de hacer un `if`, pero no logro que el resultado sea `next day` o `next week` o `next month`

Comment: No entiendo bien la situación del código, pero viendo ciertas cosas en él parecería que estás tratado de reinventar la rueda. Olvidándote de la implementación actual, para la cual has escogido a mi juicio el camino más largo, ¿podrías explicar **de manera teórica** en un breve párrafo cuál es el **contexto** y qué es **lo que quieres hacer** (sería decir simplemente: *tengo estos datos y quiero hacer esto*)? Pregunto esto porque me parece que partiendo de objetos `DateTime` puede hacer los cálculos que quieras sin complicaciones. Pero el código es confuso, no se entiende el contexto.

Comment: Si en la base tenes cargadas las fechas en Año, mes y día, no tiene mucho sentido que calcules las horas de diferencia. Porque estas tomando una hora que no tenes, seguramente estas usando las 0 horas. Asi que un valor menor a 24 horas tendria q dar un resultado al estilo de "Today".
Me parece que para resolverlo seria mas facil usar directamente desde la consulta de SQL la funcion **DATEDIFF** calculando en días.
Y si queres despues lo pasas a meses o años.

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es que figure en la lista de pedido los pedidos a futuro. Ejemplo: si el pedido fue realizado el dia 18-03 el resultado va a ser `1 days ago` pero cuando el pedido es para el 21-03 el resultado tendria que ser `next 2 day`. Cuando llega la fecha del pedido deberia mostrar `today`.